# Why does this while-loop condition stay true?

Tags: c++, while-loop

The error here is that the number never stops increasing (0 -> infinite). Why doesn't the loop stop once totalCareTime hits 25?

```
   int totalCareTime = 0;

   while (totalCareTime <= 25 || interrupted == false)
   {
       ++totalCareTime;
       cout << totalCareTime << endl;


       if (time == time + emergencySam || time == time + emergencySid)
       {
           interrupted = true;
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `||`, so as long as either condition is true, the loop continues. If `interrupted` stays `false` (which will always be the case unless `emergencySam` or `emergencySid` have a value of `0`; it's unclear how they are set or whether they can be changed at all), the loop will go forever. Change to `&&` if you need both conditions to be true for the loop to keep going.